# How to fetch data in react native if we created backend with nodejs and mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, react-native, express

So i am very new to react native, but i got little bit understanding in react node express and mysql.let's just say i created backend with node js, express and mysql so how we fetch the data from react native, is it same way like what we do in react ?

Comment: Yes ,You can use **axios** .

REF --> https://blog.logrocket.com/using-axios-react-native-manage-api-requests/

Comment: So using axios huh, so its still work like react app in some way ? guess i try, and is it better to use mysql and node or just use like firebase ? thanks btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is the exact same way you'd do it with React, so you most commonly will have 4 options:

1. [Axios](https://axios-http.com/docs/intro)
2. [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)
3. [React Query](https://react-query-v3.tanstack.com/)
4. [RTK Query](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/overview) (Which I recommend especially if you'll be using redux in your app)

Answer (score 0):

Same as React.
You can just use fetch like this:

```
import {useEffect} from "react";
const fetchData = () => {
return fetch("...")
 .then((response) => response.json())
 .then((data) => console.log(data));}
 
useEffect(() => {
 fetchData();
 }, []);
```